# Temp Ban command discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried to code a temp ban command. Unfortunately that command doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. I don't get any error codes it just doesn't work.

```js
case 'tempban':

if(!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS)) return;

const member = message.mentions.first()
if(!member) return;

let time = args[1]
if(!time) return;
let timer = ms(time)

message.channel.send('The User is banned')


await member.ban({reason: `User was banned by ${message.author.tag} for ${time}` })
await setTimeout(async function () {
    await message.guild.members.unban(member.id)

}, timer)


break;
```

Comment: You have multiple early returns that give no feedback the command has failed. Perhaps, for debugging purposes, you should instruct your bot to write a message stating when arguments are missing or in the wrong format.

Comment: It's possible for `ms(time)` to be invalid since there's no format restriction for `time`

Comment: I downloaded [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) for the time, if you mean that

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the setTimeout and...

```
member.ban({ days: days, reason: reason });
```